# how to Use useSelectedTabCookie in struts2 jquery library

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jquery plugin first time. I am using a tabbedpanel and everything works fine. The only problem is, I am not able to find the selected tab in my action class. I tried couple of ways using onClick, onFocus etc etc but not working. I want to know how we can sue useSelectedTabCookie in tabbedpanel.

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" selectedTab="%{selectedTab}" useSelectedTabCookie="true">
<sj:tab id="div1" target="pendingDiv" loadingText="Loading..." indicator="indicator" >
</sj:tab>
<sj:tabbedpanel>
```

Thanks

Comment: So you want to get opened tab id in your action, right?

Comment: Hi Aleksanr. yes thats what i wanted and implemented with this code
    $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#tabpanel').tabs({
          select:function(event,ui) { //bind click event to link
                selectedTab=ui.index;
          }
        });
  });
$( "#tabpanel" ).tabs( "load", selectedTab);

Thanks for considering